# LiveData which can be refreshed from UI with a repository function that returns a new LiveData each time?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a method as follow in the repository class which returns list of countries either from local database or from network as LiveData:

```
fun loadCountries(): LiveData<Resource<List<Country>>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Country>, List<CountryResponse>>() {
        ...
    }.asLiveData()
}
```

In ViewModel, I have a LiveData that keeps the returning LiveData:

```
class CountryViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val countryListResource: LiveData<Resource<List<Country>>> = countryRepository.loadCountries()

    fun refresh() {
        // How to assign new LiveData returned by countryRepository.loadCountries() here?
        // SwitchMap needs other LiveData to be used.
    }
}
```

User should be able to refresh data and that's where my problem arises. I need to inject new LiveData returned by `countryRepository.loadCountries()` into `countryListResource` and I don't know how to achieve this?

If I do `countryListResource = countryRepository.loadCountries()` (which I cannot since it is `val`), the observer needs to stop observing previous one and start observing the latest one.

If I use swichMap on `countryListResource`, I need another MutableLiveData to trigger a new call from the repository, as shown [here](https://www.ivanalvarado.com/blog/swipe-to-refresh-with-livedata-and-mvvm-android).

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple.
First in your repository class create mutable say obj1 and immutable say obj2 live data objects of type country list.
Obj2 is initialised with obj1.Then `loadCountry()` function should update only the obj1.

Your view model should observe the obj2 using `observeForever()`.
Then view model also do create two obj same as repo say obj3 and obj4 resp. Observe the obj4 in your activity. Obj3 is getting updated using `postValue()` in `observeForever()`  and which in-turns update obj4(initialised with obj3).

Hope this helps you.

**Example:**

> Repository

```
// obj1
private val _countryLiveData : MutableLiveData<List<Country>>

// obj2
val countryLiveData : LiveData<List<Country>>
        get() = _countryLiveData

fun loadCountries() {
    val list = fetchCountryList()
    _countryLiveData.postValue(list)
}
```

> ViewModel

```
// obj3
private val _countryLiveData : MutableLiveData<List<Country>> 

// obj4  live data to be observed in activity
val countryLiveData : LiveData<List<Country>> 
    get() = _countryLiveData

init {

countryRepository.countryLiveData.observeForever { countryList ->
         this._countryLiveData.postValue(countryList)
   }
}

fun refresh() {
    countryRepository.loadCountries()  
}
```